# specman : how to make agent pointer to environment?

Tags: specman

I have an agent that waits for an environment event.
How to point the environment event in the agent?
There is no "get_env()" in Specman that could connect between agent and its environment.

Comment: Could you add a minimal code example to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use get_parent_unit() like in

```
var my_env_u: parent = get_parent_unit().as_a(my_env_u);
```